# How to change headers of a CSV file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to change the headers of a CSV file, however I am only able to change the rows of data, and not the headers.

I tried looking at other examples, however they did not work. I have been looking at some of the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), however it is still not working.

Here is how I am trying to do it right now:

```
input = File.open TestFile, 'r' #read
output = File.open TestFile, 'w' #write
CSV.filter input, output, :headers => true, :write_headers => true, :return_headers => true do |csv|
  csv << ["Test"] if row.header_row?
end
```

Comment: You are opening `TestFile` to read, then to write. You can't do that. As soon as you try opening a file for writing it'll be truncated. You have to write to a separate file.

Comment: Please add a minimal example of your CSV file that you're reading, and an example of that file after rewriting the headers. Don't make us generate our own; We need to all use the same sandbox toys. Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to change the headers of a CSV file using a ruby script,

The general rule is: `You cannot change what is already written to a file`. You can erase a file and write anew to a file. You can append to a file. But you cannot make changes to what is already written.

```
require 'csv'

input = File.open 'input.txt', 'r' #read
output = File.open 'output.txt', 'w' #write

CSV.filter input, output, :headers => true, :write_headers => true, :return_headers => true do |row|
  row << "Test" if row.header_row?
end

--output:--
$ cat input.txt
col1,col2
10,20
30,40
~/ruby_programs$ rm output.txt 
remove output.txt? y
~/ruby_programs$ ruby my_prog.rb 
~/ruby_programs$ cat output.txt
col1,col2,Test
10,20
30,40
```

Comment: It did not work. I just replaced all of the cells with empty values, did not change the headers.

Answer (score 0):

A quick analyze of what you are doing:

You open a file for reading:

```
input = File.open TestFile, 'r' #read
```

You open the same file for reading - this deletes the content.

```
output = File.open TestFile, 'w' #write
```

You read the now empty file:

```
CSV.filter input, output, :headers => true, :write_headers => true, :return_headers => true do |csv|
  puts "I'm here" ## <- My addition to show you never in the loop.
  csv << ["Test"] if row.header_row?
end
```

**A possible Solution:**

You have to define different in- and output files and make a manual header definition:

```
#Prepare some test data
TestFile = 'test.csv'
File.open(TestFile, 'w'){|f|
 f << <<csv
a;b;c
1;2;3
1;2;3
csv
}

require 'csv'
input = File.open TestFile, 'r' #read
output = File.open('x.csv', 'w') #write

output << "new a; new b;new b"
CSV.filter input, output, :headers => true, :write_headers => true do |row|
end

input.close
output.close
#You may delete the input file and rename output file
```

as an alternative you may define your own header:

```
CSV.filter( input, output, 
          :headers => true, #remove header from input
          :out_headers => [:xa,:xb, :xc], #define output header
          :write_headers => true, 
        )  do |row|
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
input = File.open TestFile, 'r' #read
output = File.open TestFile, 'w' #write
```

The line that opens the file for writing is truncating it so that when you read the file as input there is nothing there.

As 7stud shows in his answer you need to have separate files for input and output.

```
input = File.open 'input.txt', 'r' #read
output = File.open 'output.txt', 'w' #write
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rows = CSV.open("input.csv").read
rows.shift
rows = new_headers << rows
CSV.open("output.csv", "w") { |csv| csv.write(rows) }
```

By the way, you don't have to write them to an output file if you don't want to, at least in this example.

Comment: I also have add in data to the cells, and already have a method for doing that. How can I combine both where it creates the headers, and then populates the cells with data after?